# Why am I getting this error while using gedit?

Tags: gedit, glib

> (gedit:4778): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `object->ref_count > 0'    failed

What does this error mean?

Comment: Are you starting gedit from the command line?  How are you invoking it?

Comment: yeah, im using gksu gedit ... in the terminal

Comment: Those error message can usually be ignored unless gedit isn't working for you. Feel free to report the bug to LP though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a harmless message that you will see popup when running most gtk applications on the command line. You can ignore it really. I'm not sure what causes it, but usually it's no problem, unless you are getting other problems with the application.