# Error installing Android SDK

Tags: java, android, jdk

When trying to follow step 3 of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/466245/543493), I get an error when launching `./android` command from the folder `android-sdk-linux/tools folder`:

> > perissf@perissf-ubuntu:~/Scaricati/android-sdk-linux/tools$ ./android
> >
> > (Android SDK Manager:6135): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed
> >
> > (Android SDK Manager:6135): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed

However, despite the error, the Android SDK Manager window opens anyway.

In the system there are the preinstalled Java and OpenJDK, but I have installed the Oracle JRE and set it as default:

> > perissf@perissf-ubuntu:~$ java -version
> >
> > java version "1.8.0_101"
> >
> > Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
> >
> > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
> >
> > perissf@perissf-ubuntu:~$ javac -version
> >
> > Il programma "javac" può essere trovato nei seguenti pacchetti:
> >
> > - default-jdk
> > - ecj
> > - gcj-5-jdk
> > - openjdk-8-jdk-headless
> > - gcj-4.8-jdk
> > - gcj-4.9-jdk
> > - openjdk-9-jdk-headless
> >
> > Provare: sudo apt install `<PACCHETTO SELEZIONATO>`

And my question is: should I care about this error or go on anyway?

Comment: These are harmless warnings meant for devs and you will usually see them when opening GTK apps from the terminal. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/23423/why-am-i-getting-this-error-while-using-gedit for example. There are plenty of similar questions on this site regarding this.