# Why am I getting GLib errors when I launch Firefox?

Tags: command-line, firefox, glib

I am new to Linux and have been poking around a lot in Terminal. I launched Firefox from the command line and noticed that I began getting the below. It still opens and seems to run as it should. I don't remember seeing this *before* deleting Chrome or *before* using proxychains. Any thoughts?

```
(firefox:8321): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:8321): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:8321): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:8321): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
```

Comment: See [Why am I getting this error while using gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/q/23423) However, if you're looking for the cause, we might not want to close this question as a duplicate; the answer there doesn't address that. ...What command are you running? Just `firefox`, or something else? Is there any other output in the terminal when you run it? What version of Ubuntu? Do the messages appear if you don't use proxychains? (I understand you might not be able to test that, for security reasons. So if not, please don't sweat it.) I recommend editing your question to provide this additional info.

Comment: Just run `firefox &>/dev/null &`. Those are useless messages spewed by a graphics library. (Despite the scary CRITICAL tag, they are actually utterly unimportant.) There is nothing else you can do about them.

Comment: @AlexP, I have noticed that too when  I launch app from terminal. Why is that the case, if the app works fine why the error messages ?

Comment: @George: Those are debugging messages produced by a graphics library. Why they are displayed unconditionally in production builds is a mystery for the ages.

Comment: Also see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/422400/248158